# Using Python3, i want to reduce if-elif code

Tags: loops, for-loop, python-3.8

hi below my code example. Is there a way to reduce the number of lines of code and save time?

example.. using function.. i need any other method. please help

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cZo7u.png)

Comment: please add the code as text, not as picture. It will be easier for the others to copy->paste->modify.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes. You can get the list by name from `globals()`. See the example below:

```py
list1 = []
list2 = []

msg = {
    'type': 2
}

def addToList(listNumber, msg):
    globals()["list" + str(listNumber)].append(msg)

for key, val in msg.items():
    if key == 'type':
        addToList(val, msg)

print(list1) #[]
print(list2) #[{'type': 2}]
```